# Codeigniter: What is the best practice to maintain multiple database connection datas?

Tags: codeigniter, database-connection

My typical development pattern is:

```
1 - local work machine 

2 - online testing server 

3 - production server.
```

Each of these has a database with unique connection data.

So for my projects I use a config file that implements a `switch( what_environment ){ // assign appropriate db connection info }` that assigns the proper db connection info (host, username, password, db name, ...) depending on the environment.

However in codeigniter's `/config/database.php`, there is no such construct, but rather just *one* set of properties. Obviously I can put my own server-sniffing switch statement in there. But I am presuming that there is a codeigniter way of handling this.

Can anyone shed light on the proper codeigniter way of maintaining multiple db connection infos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your application/config/constants.php write:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); 


switch(ENVIRONMENT):

case 'development': 
# DB 
defined('DB_HOST')      ? null : define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
defined('DB_USER')      ? null : define('DB_USER', 'root');
defined('DB_PASSWORD')  ? null : define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
defined('DB_NAME')      ? null : define('DB_NAME', 'dev_db');
break; 

case 'production': 
# DB 
defined('DB_HOST')      ? null : define('DB_HOST', 'production');
defined('DB_USER')      ? null : define('DB_USER', 'production_user');
defined('DB_PASSWORD')  ? null : define('DB_PASSWORD', '12345');
defined('DB_NAME')      ? null : define('DB_NAME', 'production_db');
break; 

endswitch;
```

Then on your application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(

    'hostname' => DB_HOST,
    'username' => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
    'database' => DB_NAME,

);
```

Comment: this seems like the answer .. but using the ENVIRONMENT variable requires having to manually set it every time you upload to a different server. I use server-sniffing to automate that (analyze the $_SERVER[ "DOCUMENT_ROOT" ]  string ) ... thanks.

Comment: Agreed! (server-sniffing method). The code above is just to show how you can set the DB connection dynamically depending on the ENVIRONMENT whether 'sniffed' or defined. Happy coding!

Comment: I do wonder though ... which is worse: to put constants into the global scope, or set them within a function scope ...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best solution, however, it is the simplest to implement and always worked very well for me:

After the declaration of $db['default']:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '...',
    'password' => '...',
    ...
);
```

I add this code:

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == 'development'){
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXX';
    $db['default']['database'] = 'developmentdatabasename';
}
```

In the index.php of your project:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Comment: this is effectively what I have, but it is not the 'codeigniter way' ... also this forces the developer to change the ENVIRONMENT variable before uploading to another server ( instead, I sniff the `$_SERVER[ "DOCUMENT_ROOT" ]` value to automatically determine which server)

Answer (score 1):

if you use apache - activate SetEnvIf (if it itsn't already)

after that put in your htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Host localhost$ CI_ENV=development
SetEnvIf Host testhost$ CI_ENV=testing
SetEnvIf Host productionhost$ CI_ENV=production
```

now just simply create in your application/config/ folder 3 folder named development, testing and production

and if you put now your different config files in this folders - ci accesses it depending on your current working environment

please follow the [CI Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html?highlight=ci_env) for further Information

Comment: this is helpful because it shows how the CI_ENV property is set within the htaccess ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

At your config/database.php you can set multiple environment like this

```
$active_group = 'local';
if(ENVIRONMENT=='development')
{
   $active_group = 'online';
}
elseif(ENVIRONMENT=='production')
{
   $active_group = 'production';
}
$db['local'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'xxxx',
'username' => '',
//other configs
);
$db['online'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
//other configs
);
$db['production'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
//other configs
);
```

You can do it lots of way.See [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases)