# How to load my function inside application\config\constants.php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to set specific custom constants when developing on my machine and our server, so I coded inside the constants.php file something like:

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_dev_environment')){
     function is_dev_environment()
     {
         //the magic
     }
{


if (is_dev_environment()){
    defined('REPORTS_DIR') OR define('REPORTS_DIR', 'downloads/reports');
}else{
    defined('REPORTS_DIR') OR define('REPORTS_DIR', 'other_dir');
}
```

that worked fine, but of course I don't want to code it in database.php as well. So I tried to put the code in an other file other.php inside the config folder and to just:

```
include "other.php";
```

and call the is_dev_environment() function, but I've got the following error:

```
Warning: include(environment_helper): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\application\config\constants.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'environment_helper' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\application\config\constants.php on line 4

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_dev_environment() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\application\config\constants.php:103 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(70): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\index.php(315): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Teilestammblatt\application\config\constants.php on line 103
```

I've tried to put the other.php file inside the helper folder renaming it to other_helper.php and autoload it, but this didn't work either and something like

```
$this->load->helper("other");
```

I am very new to codeignator and php and I couldn't find my problem on stackoverflow that was a solve to my problem. What am I missing?

**EDIT :**

```
include APPPATH.'config'.'\\yourfile.php';
```

did the trick, because I wanted to be able to do it on different environment and without to use absolute path. This include works also inside the index.php file after definend APPPATH and the $application_folder at the top of the index.php file:

```
$application_folder = 'application';

define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include APPPATH.'config'.'\\yourfile.php';
```

note that the

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

should only be defined once in inside this file or else php will show a Notice warning.

Comment: not sure - but do you realise that Codeigniter has its own Environment handling ? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36287602/3436643)

Comment: I wanted to automate this whole process, so it even will set the environment itself to development.

Comment: CodeIgniter already have defined constant `ENVIRONMENT` you can use that in `constant.php`

Comment: @jagad89 yes I know, and I'm setting the constant **ENVIRONMENT ** automatically as well now

Comment: what's next you want to achieve?

Comment: you can create a folder with your `ENVIRONMENT` name under `config` folder, and put `constants.php` under it and delete `constants.php` in `config` folder.

Comment: e.g your environment is `development` so it will automatically load `config/development/constants.php`

Comment: @jagad89 thank you, these are actually good hints. I solved it already with my functions, but in an unconvinient way, using ENVIRONMENT constant from the start would have been better. But even though I needed to write my own functions so I could set the ENVIRONMENT constant inside index.php automatically so I still needed the right include statment which I got. It is all in my EDIT answer.